# Search criteria stored in array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form:

```
<input type="text" name="srchby" />
<input type radio name="crit" value="a" />
<input type radio name="crit" value="b" />
<input type="submit" value="proceed" name="proceed"/>
```

I have an array which stores and gives search criteria whether the user chooses radio "a" or "b".

```
        $crit=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["crit"]);
        $srchby=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["srchby"]);

        $crar=array("a"=>array("column_name1","column_name2","table_name"),
        "b"=>array("column_name1","column_name2","table_name2"));

        mysql_query("SELECT '$crar[$crit][0]','$crar[$crit][1]' 
        FROM '$crar[$crit][3]' WHERE something='$srchby'");
```

Is that a good & fast option or not? Do you have any better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear how your criterias work and what you want to get from DB.

Comment: It is just a sample. I just wanna know if method is a good idea. "a" ,"b", "c" in array are representing different table and column names.

Comment: I know you want to edit you code for conciseness, but please leave it syntactically valid - it's very hard to work out what effect `$srchby=....` has on the code. Keep code examples concise and **legible**.

Comment: Ok my apologies, i will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$crit=mysql_real....($_POST["crit"]);

$crar=array("table1"=>array("field1","field2","field3"),
"table2"=>array("field1","field2","field3"));

$fieldList='';

foreach($crar[$crit] as $fields)
{
   $fieldList.=" $fields, "
}
 rtrim($fieldList,", ");

$query="select $fieldList from $crit";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think more accurate and clean version of your code would be like this:

```
$crit=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["crit"]);
$srchby=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["srchby"]);

switch($crit){
    case "a":
        mysql_query("SELECT `column_name1`, `column_name2`
                FROM `table_name1` WHERE something='$srchby'");
        break;
    case "b":
        mysql_query("SELECT `column_name1`, `column_name2`
                FROM `table_name2` WHERE something='$srchby'");
        break;

}
```